# Provisioned concurrency for AWS Lambda using Terraform : avoid recreation every time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a Provisioned concurrency for a Lambda using terraform.

Provisioned concurrency is very simple ([documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config)):

```
resource "aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config" "concurrency_config" {
  count                             = 1
  function_name                     = var.function_name 
  provisioned_concurrent_executions = var.provisioned_concurrency_lambdas 
  qualifier                         = var.function_version
}
```

yet when I re-run terraform without any change, these configs get recreated. It happens momentarily for usual Lambdas, but for a Lambda inside VPC it takes ~ 3 minutes.

How can I avoid re-creation or make sure that Lambda inside VPC does not take 3 minutes to update its Concurrency settings?

Comment: Please include the Terraform plan output that shows what it thinks is changing each time.

Comment: Have you tried with [ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes) attribute?

Comment: Also experiencing this, but using module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest